How does one handle a dataset with groups of features and groups of labels in classification?
I have a large dataset (1.8mil samples). There are 15 features: x1, y1, z1, e1, d1, x2,..., d3. (x,y,z) are coordinates, e is energy, and d is a derived feature- Euclidean distance between the coordinates. The set (xi, yi, zi, ei) represents an event- so each sample is three events. The task is to classify each sample as 1 of 13 classes: type 1 (trash), type 2 (and then 1 of 6 permutations), or type 3 (and then 1 of 6 permutations). Each permutation orders the three events. Without going into too much detail about where the data comes from, it's related to scattering interactions and imaging; there is a classical way to reorder type 3, I'm not sure about the rest of the task.
It seems clear to me that there are 'groups' of features- each of the events, and 'groups' of labels- each of the types. (I'm not sure if my language is correct, but it seems these features/labels are 'correlated'.) I am new to data science and at this point I have opted to ignore these groups and just put the data straight into a number of models (both ML and DL). I have tried random forests, XGBoost, fully connected deep NNs, CNNs, and some newer DL architectures built for tabular data in the literature (e.g. Tabnet, DANet). (My dataset matches many characteristics of tabular data, but is notably not heterogeneous.) I have also done some preprocessing such as normalization.
Everything has achieved under 60% accuracy on both training and validation (except the fcn, which is under 70%), so it seems as though something is very wrong. At this point, there is no explicit accounting of these aforementioned 'groups', so I feel that my natural next step is to directly address the groups (perhaps via preprocessing or feature engineering or a specific model/tuning), but after a fair amount of research I have no idea how to proceed. I'm not even sure if my approach of making each permutation a label makes sense. I have also considered splitting up the task into first classifying the type and then the permutation, but preliminary tests weren't looking good. (I also tried making a custom loss function to have a greater penalty for guesses outside of the type.) Any guidance would be greatly appreciated (either on the group issue, or just the issue of getting very bad accuracy)!

Can you explain what you mean by 'type 2 (and then 1 of 6 permutations)'?

yes- each sample has three events (each event is described by (x, y, z, e)) in a particular order which may be incorrect. if the sample is of type 1, then it is trash and will not be used in imaging. if the sample is of type 2 or 3, however, it can be used in imaging but must be reordered. so the task is to classify it as type 2 or 3 AND FURTHER classify it as one of the six possible permutations of the events. hence there is 13 total classes.
